# Using xpath to locate element with an underline in the name

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, unique

I am trying to click on a webelement that changes ID and xpath dynamically. I dont see any other information that can be used directly to identify the element uniquely everytime the page loads.

Here is the Xpath for the element:

```
.//*[@id='isc_SB']/table/tbody/tr/td
```

This will be updated along with ID at every page load.

Here is the HTML code for the same element:

```
<table width="74px" height="30px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="OBToolbarTextButtonFocusedOver" valign="center" nowrap="true" align="center" onfocus="isc_OBToolbarActionButton_3.$47()" tabindex="-1">
Pu
<u>b</u>
lish
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**I want to click on the button with Text called "publish" with 'u' having an underline**

Here is what i have tried to no success:

Attempt 1:

```
publish = //td[. = 'Pu<u>b</u>lish']
```

Attempt 2:

```
publish = //td[contains(text(), 'lish')]
```

Attempt 3:

```
publish = .//*[@id='isc_S7']/table/tbody/tr/td # this is just an example to show id, xpath and everything is dynamic.
```

Please assist. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath the string value of an element node is defined as the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes, so if you have a

```
<td>Pu<u>b</u>lish</td>
```

then you can match it using simply

```
//td[. = 'Publish']
```

If, as in your question, there are newlines either side of the `u` element then you need to be a bit more creative, e.g.

```
//td[normalize-space() = 'Pu b lish']
```

If you want to cover both cases then

```
//td[translate(normalize-space(), ' ', '') = 'Publish']
```

As an aside, the reason your attempt 2 didn't work is that `contains` expects both its arguments to be strings, but in your example `text()` gives you a set of *two* text nodes ("Pu" and "lish"), and converting a node set to a string means taking the value of just the *first* node in the set in document order and ignoring the other(s).

Comment: Thank you @ian roberts, for the wonderful explanation and answer, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can accomplish that using JUST `xpath`. As a workaround this might help

```
//td[contains(text(),'Pu')]/u[text()='b']
```